# Using Html.RadioButtonFor with a boolean isn't writing Checked="Checked"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue using the RadioButtonFor helper.  When the value passed in is true, it isn't displaying a "check" in either radio button.  When the value is false, it works just fine.

I copied this code from the project I am working on and created a sample application and I was able to replicate the issue.  If I hard coded the value to true or false it seems to work, but when I use the "!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allgroups)" it doesn't.

From the View:

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups, true) All Groups
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups, false) Current Groups
</div>
```

From the ViewModel:

```
    public bool AllGroups { get; set; }
```

From the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string allgroups)
{
    var model = new ProgramGroupIndexViewModel
      {
          AllGroups = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(allgroups)
      };
    return View(model);
}
```

From view source in IE:

```
<div>
    <input id="AllGroups" name="AllGroups" type="radio" value="True" /> All Groups
    <input id="AllGroups" name="AllGroups" type="radio" value="False" /> Current Groups
</div>
```

From view source when value of AllGroups is false (note it works):

```
<div>
    <input id="AllGroups" name="AllGroups" type="radio" value="True" /> All Groups
    <input checked="checked" id="AllGroups" name="AllGroups" type="radio" value="False" /> Current Groups
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binding is getting confused because you named your action parameter the same as your model property.  Change the name of your `Index` action parameter, and it should work.

```
public ActionResult Index(string showAllGroups)
{
    var model = new ProgramGroup
                    {
                        AllGroups = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(showAllGroups);
                    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are returning bool from model then there is no need to check uncheck explicitly mvc will do it itself just write

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups) 
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups)
</div>
```

however if you want to do it explicitly then

you should use following syntax to check / uncheck

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups, "DisplayText", new { @checked = "checked" })
```

In source code you can see that it is setting true / false for value not checked attribute

in your view you can write

```
@if(m.AllGroups)
{
  Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups, "DisplayText", new { @checked = "checked" })
}
else
{
   Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups, "DisplayText" })
}
```

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AllGroups) is an error "Can't resolve method".